# Cannot Center Column Widget

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I am new to flutter and i am trying to centre all the widgets inside column widget but its not working. I tried encapsulating column into centre widget but its still the same and aligned with the top of screen. Below is my code, please have a look and let me know what i am doing wrong. Thanks :)

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class SignIn extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'SignIn Screen',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 26.0),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
            ),
            TextField(
              maxLength: 25,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Enter username',
              ),
            ),
            TextField(
              maxLength: 25,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Enter password',
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  RaisedButton(
                    child: Text('SignIn'),
                    onPressed: _signIn,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future _signIn() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setBool('isLoggedIn', true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add `MainAxisAlignment.center` and remove `Expanded`

```
class SignIn extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'SignIn Screen',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 26.0),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
            ),
            TextField(
              maxLength: 25,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Enter username',
              ),
            ),
            TextField(
              maxLength: 25,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Enter password',
              ),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
                    child: Text('SignIn'),
                    onPressed: _signIn,
                  ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 18):

### Center vertically

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[ ... ],
)
```

### Center horizontally

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[ ... ],
)
```

But if the column is hugging its content then just wrap it in a Center widget

```
Center(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[ ... ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: Why is the `Center` widget needed in the last code snippet?  I consider myself more than a novice when it comes to Flutter and this very basic layout issue still confuses me.

Comment: @jaredbaszler If the column width is already as narrow as it can be since it is hugging its elements, then trying to center the elements within the column width won't do anything. The `Center` widget centers its child within the parent of the `Center` widget assuming the parent is bigger than the child of `Center`. So if the width of the Column widget is less than the width of the parent of the Center widget, then using Center will center Column, which will in turn center the column elements.

Comment: got it - thanks for the explanation.  So I think then your comment in the 3rd snippet needs to read "is not hugging"?

Comment: @jaredbaszler, No, I meant hugging. That is, the column width has the same width as its elements and not the same width as the parent. That's the only way that using `Center` will work.

Answer (score 1):

For centering vertically,

```
Center(
   child:Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[ ... ],
   )
)
```